# object reference not set to an instance of object sending empty value to sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I get this error

> object reference not set to an instance of object

when trying to send empty value to a SQL Server database. The column accepts `NULL` values. This is the code of my table

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[numeroreporte] [varchar](100) NULL,
[dias] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[lugar] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[workorder] [int] NULL,
[InOutHour] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[overtime] [int] NULL,
[emergencia] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[viaje] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[almuerzo] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
[peaje] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
[otros] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
```

This is my code in c#:

```
public void datosReporte ( DataGridView dgv,  Label linkLB )
{
    sqlCOMM = new SqlCommand("InsertarDatosReporte", sqlCON);
    sqlCOMM.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@numeroreporte", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar); 
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_dias", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar) ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_lugar", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar) ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_workorder", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar) ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_InOutHour", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar) ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_overtime", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).ToString() ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_emergencia", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar) ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_viaje", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar) ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_almuerzo", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal) ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_peaje", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal) ;
    sqlCOMM.Parameters.Add("@sp_otros", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal);

    try
    {
        sqlCON.Open();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            if (!row.IsNewRow)
            {  
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@numeroreporte"].Value =linkLB.Text; 
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_dias"].Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_lugar"].Value = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_workorder"].Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_InOutHour"].Value = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_overtime"].Value = row.Cells[4].Value;
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_emergencia"].Value = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_viaje"].Value = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_almuerzo"].Value = row.Cells[7].Value;
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_peaje"].Value = row.Cells[8].Value;
                sqlCOMM.Parameters["@sp_otros"].Value = row.Cells[9].Value; 

                sqlCOMM.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCON.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which parameter having empty value/which line is causing the problem? and by empty you mean `null`?

Comment: How you try to send null value? Which of the parameters is null?

Comment: SQL does not support `where val = NULL` it supports `where val IS NULL`, so you can't just throw `null` as a value.

Comment: yuriry, empty cell in datagridview

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan, all parameters are null, but when i see that error, i put default values. But if the user erase that value and send that empty value this catch appears.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get suggests to me that one of the cells where you use `Value.ToString()` actually contains `null`.  You can't call `ToString` on an object that doesn't exist.

One solution is for you to check the cell `Value` first and, if it's `null`, assign `DBNull.Value` to the `Value` of the parameter.  A better option would be to simply bind the grid to a `DataTable` and then empty cells would contain `DBNull.Value` by default.  You would simply use a data adapter to save all the changes from the `DataTable` back to the database in a batch, so there would be no loop.

Comment: jmcilhinney, im not have much experience but, but if you says that you write, in c sharp code i will understand better.